# Variable inside of a variable batch

Tags: batch-file

I made this code

```
@echo off & SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
title TXTanimation
set dir101=C:\USers\%username%\Desktop\file.bat
goto label1
echo Lets make a text animation
pause
set /p dir101=where will the .bat be saved:
:label1
echo @ECHO OFF > %dir101%
echo: >> %dir101%
:menu
echo 0=Edit important information
echo 1=Display .txt
echo 2=Play sound
echo 3=Close sound player
echo 4=Add nessicary wait between .txt
echo 5=Label point
echo 6=Edit variable
    echo 7=Goto point
echo 8=Create IF sentence
echo 9=End it
    echo Add - to the front to view it's guide!    
    Set /p choose=which one:

If '%choose%'=='0' (
SEt /p title=What is the title
:LOL101
set /p color=what color do you want type test to experiment with the colors
If '!color!'=='test' goto tester
goto model
:tester
SEt /p test=Please give hexadecimal number type exit to leave:
if '!test!'=='exit' goto LOL101
color !test!
goto tester
:model
echo title %title% >> %dir101%
echo color %color% >> %dir101%
goto menu
)

If '%choose%'=='-0' (
echo The title is on the top of the screen. The color of the text and backround is a hexadecimal number its 

01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,0A,0B,0C,0D,0E,0F,10,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,1A,1B,1C,1D,1E,1F,20,21,23,24,25...FB,FC,FD,FE. There really are 

values with the same character but those are not valid colors in batch.
goto menu
)
If '%choose%'=='1' (
set /p dir=what is the dir of your .txt:
echo cls >> %dir101%
echo type %dir% >> %dir101%
goto menu
)
If '%choose%'=='-1' (
echo These pictures are what will be shown in the animation.
goto menu
)
If '%choose%'=='2' (
SEt /p dirx=What is the directory of the music file:
echo start !dirx! >> %dir101%
goto menu
)
If '%choose%'=='-2' (
    echo Windows will open these sound files but may not automatically play them. If they are automatically played they should be opened one 

nessicary wait before wanted time.
goto menu
    )
If '%choose%'=='3' (
echo taskkill /PID wmplayer.exe >> %dir101%
goto menu
)
If '%choose%'=='-3' (
echo This closes the sound window when you play a sound. It should be played after a couple nessicary waits or when the sound is finished.
goto menu
)
If '%choose%'=='4' (
SEt /p thyme=How much milliseconds 250 is usual:
echo ping 192.168.1.1 -n 1 -w !thyme! ^>NUL >>%dir101%
goto menu
)
If '%choose%'=='-4' (
echo These waits are extremely important and should be used almost after every .txt.
goto menu
)
    If '%choose%'=='5' (
SEt /p point=what do you want the point to be labeled as:
echo :!point! >> %dir101%
goto menu
)
If '%choose%'=='-5' (
echo You use this to label points where your animation can go back to.
goto menu
)
If '%choose%'=='6' (
:Y
SEt /p answ=Is this a math variable y/n
If !answ!==y goto yes
If !answ!==n goto no
goto Y
:yes
SEt /p name=variable name
set /p form=variable formula
echo Set /a !name!=!form! >> %dir101%
goto T
:no
SEt /p name=variable name
set /p form=variable value
echo Set !name!=!form! >> %dir101%
:T
goto menu
)
If '%choose%'=='-6' (
echo Variables can be used to count the number of times something has shown so you. If you put %variable name% it will use the value of that 

variable.
goto menu
)
If '%choose%'=='7' (
SEt /p point=What point do you want to go to:
echo goto !point! >> %dir101%
goto menu
)
If '%choose%'=='-7' (
echo This is used to go back to points. THis is where you make infinite loops.
goto menu
)
If '%choose%'=='8' (
set /p var=which variable do you want to use
set /p string=What value should be questioned
SET /p poin=What is the name of the point
echo If '%!var!%'=='!string!' goto !poin! >> %dir101%
goto menu
)
If '%choose%'=='-8' (
echo IF sentences are usually used to do a command after a variable is a certain number.
goto menu
)
If '%choose%'=='-9' (
echo This is to close the batch.
goto menu
)
If '%choose%'=='9' (
echo Thanks for making
pause
exit /b
)
```

Now you probaly see the %!var!% yeh that needs to be %variablename% any idea? I need to explain more so the rest of the batch is done gonna ship it off after this error is fixed! Well before that I still need to go erase that part where It answers its own question at teh beginning!

This question involves how to have variable in batch files expand to the names of other variables, and then resolve those.

Comment: Is there a question here somewhere?

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question).

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn how to distill your code down to the minimal code needed to pose your question, and then ask a specific question.

That being said, I think I understand your problem.

I believe you are dynamically building a batch script, and you want your code to look like

```
echo If '%someVar%'=='someString' goto someLabel
```

All you need to do to get your percents in the output is double them up

```
echo If '%%!var!%%'=='!string!' goto !poin! >> %dir101%
```